# Make UIImageView Go Up Then Down Swift

Tags: ios, uiimageview, swift

I need to make a UIImageView animate up when the screen is tapped then back down when it hits the top.

This is the code I have got at the moment:

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(self.playerImagePhone.frame, self.floorImagePhone.frame)) {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4) {
                self.playerImagePhone.center = CGPointMake(self.playerImagePhone.center.x, self.playerImagePhone.center.y - 50)
                println("player jumped")
            }
        }
}

    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4) {
            self.playerImagePhone.center = CGPointMake(self.playerImagePhone.center.x, self.playerImagePhone.center.y + 50)
            println("player jumped")
    }
}
```

This code is working to make it go up then back down but the problem is that it allows the user to hold their finger on the screen and the image will stay up. How can I make it go down as soon as the image is finished going up?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried userInteractionEnabled = NO until it is done coming down?

Comment: This resulted in the user being able to still stay up there until they touch the screen again. Thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 1):

touchesBegan can be called often... it probably isn't  a good idea to perform your animations in there. You'll probably want to update a seperate object maintaining the animation, then once the animation is done (once the duration is over) you run another animation to bring the image back down.

As an alternative you can use also use animateWithDuration:animations:completion: and calling the down animation within the completion block.

Comment: I will try these now. Will let you know how I go. Thanks for the reply

Comment: How do I check when the duration is over? I moved my code into a different function and I don't know how to check when the duration of the animation is over

Comment: Any code provided in the completion block will be run once the animation is completed. I would use that to run the down animation.

Comment: How do I open the completion block? I currently have UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4) {
    } for the animation. Where does completion go?

Comment: UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { view.alpha = 0.0 }, completion: { _ in view.removeFromSuperview() })

Comment: With this Xcode throws me an error that says "Could not find an overload for 'animateWithDuration' that accepts the supplied arguments". Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: No I haven't done anything with swift yet. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:completion:

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. I will keep looking and read through this documentation. The code directly from their website is giving me an error...